# Writing loops for triangle elements

Tags: mesh

[image]

I'm kind of new to using Mathematica, so any help is great.  I'm trying to write a program that will create a list or matrix that will give each small triangle's point numbers.  For example if given an isosceles right triangle, the example below gives the sides as 4 and the numbering of the points is just like below, then it should give a list or table such as

```
dat= {{1,2,6},{2,3,7},{3,4,8},{4,5,9},{6,7,10},{7,8,11},{8,9,12},{10,11,13},
   {11,12,14},{13,14,15},{2,6,7},{3,7,8},{4,8,9},{7,10,11},{8,11,12},{11,13,14}}.
```

I've tried writing a few loops, but am not getting anywhere.  I know that the starting number on the diagonal of the big triangle will add whatever the side is and start decreasing that value as u go up.  For example, the first point always starts at 1, and as u move up the rows of triangle, you add `1+(x+1)` to get 6.  Then going up the next row of triangles, it is `6+(x)`, to get 10.  And so on.  So I see two iterators? once increasing? one decreasing? Any help or ideas will be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for the final `Plot/Graphic`?

Comment: Please improve your title to something more descriptive

Comment: @Öskå no, not the graph/plot, I'm looking for it to just generate those numbers of dat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A revision of my earlier, hurried function:

```
fn[_, 0] := {}

fn[s_:1, n_] := Join[
    Rest @ Array[Thread @ {#, # + {n, 1}, # + n + 1} &, n, s, Join], 
    fn[s + n + 1, n - 1]
  ]
```

Test:

```
fn[4]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 6}, {2, 6, 7}, {2, 3, 7}, {3, 7, 8}, {3, 4, 8}, {4, 8, 9}, {4, 5, 9},
>  {6, 7, 10}, {7, 10, 11}, {7, 8, 11}, {8, 11, 12}, {8, 9, 12}, {10, 11, 13},
>  {11, 13, 14}, {11, 12, 14}, {13, 14, 15}}
> ```

It is a recursive function that calls itself.  It operates line by line; it keeps track of two values: `s` which is the starting number (defaulting to one), and `n` which is the number of lines left to go (your input value to begin with).  I shall try to add a full breakdown of the code later.

---

#### Breakdown

Starting from the innermost part I wrote a [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) that takes a single number and returns the corresponding triangle points, given the correct value for `n`.  For point `3` in the bottom line of your diagram:

```
n = 4; (* there are four lines above point 3 *)

{#, # + {n, 1}, # + n + 1} &[3]
```

> ```
> {3, {7, 4}, 8}
> ```

This represents two paths, either 3, 7, 8 or 3, 4, 8; I expand it using [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html):

```
Thread @ {3, {7, 4}, 8}
```

> ```
> {{3, 7, 8}, {3, 4, 8}}
> ```

I use this function in [`Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Array.html), with the additional parameter `s` which is the starting number for that line.  For the first line in the diagram it is `1`, for the second `6`, the third `10`, etc.  Using the second line as an example:

```
n = 3;
s = 6;
Array[Thread @ {#, # + {n, 1}, # + n + 1} &, n, s, Join]
```

> ```
> {{6, 9, 10}, {6, 7, 10}, {7, 10, 11}, {7, 8, 11}, {8, 11, 12}, {8, 9, 12}}
> ```

Note that we have an incorrect triplet: {6, 9, 10}.  This occurs at the start of each line because the line above is one element shorter; I get rid of it using [`Rest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rest.html).

We now have a function to generate triplets for each line.  To find all lines I have the function call itself with the parameters for the line above it and [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Join.html) the results.  When the outer function (`fn`) is called with `0` for parameter `n` meaning "zero lines above" it returns an empty set (`{}`) and the recursion terminates.

Comment: thanks! I'm testing this out, and it seems to work.  I notice you are creating functions there. When you have time, can you explain what each line is doing? It will help me to understand this kind of programming better.  Thanks again!

Comment: @user13511 I'll try to remember to explain this, but it's beautiful weather this week for the first time in a while, so I'll be spending my free time outdoors.

Comment: @user13511 Breakdown complete.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A much belated exercise in

**Using `Partition` and `Riffle`:**

```
n = 5;
Sort /@
 Catenate[
  Partition[#, 3, 1] &@
     Riffle[First@#, Last@#] & /@
   Partition[
    TakeList[Range[Total[Range[n]]], Range[n, 1, -1]]
    , 2, 1]
  ]
```

> {{1, 2, 6}, {2, 6, 7}, {2, 3, 7}, {3, 7, 8}, {3, 4, 8}, {4, 8, 9}, {4,
> 5, 9}, {6, 7, 10}, {7, 10, 11}, {7, 8, 11}, {8, 11, 12}, {8, 9,
> 12}, {10, 11, 13}, {11, 13, 14}, {11, 12, 14}, {13, 14, 15}}